# Intel XDK New Crosswalk Build : Error Analyzing Package

Tags: intel-xdk, crosswalk-runtime

I am newbie in mobile app development , and i have litle problem with my mobile app ,,
i using Crosswalk Build For Android in Intel XDK New to develop my mobile app ,

when using Crosswalk For Android, build server gave me 2 download link , for ARM type APK and For X86 type APK

i try to downloaded and install both of it ,but it can't be instaled on device , it has a massage "Error , Problem Analyzing Package" , does anyone know solution for this problem ?

Comment: Can you send link to the APKs, so we can analyze and check whats going on?

Comment: solved ,it was just error because bad inet connection when i download the apk ,, thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you only install x86 apk for x86 devices (usually Intel processors) and ARM for ARM devices (usually AMD processors). You do not need to install both, just one or the other. You can do a Google search of your device and look at the processor/cpu type in the specification or detailed description of the device you are using. You can also usually find processor information in the Settings >> About on the device.